# Implement TcpListener into SignalR hub

Tags: c#, server, signalr, signalr-hub, tcplistener

I am working on an SignalR project. Consider the [Windows Forms Chat](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b) application example, the SignalR "Hello World" example. On my project I need to send files to the hub, but using SignalR methods has performance issues. So I searched and tested the TCP file transfer, which was ok. But to send files through TCP Client, you need to setup a TCP server. My question is, it is possible to run a TCP listener into the SignalR Hub? This is the [TCP Listener server code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) and the the [TCP Client code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx). The both examples, SignalR and TCP example works great separated, running both on localhost. Is there a way to merge the TCP Listener into SignalR Hub?

Comment: It would be significantly easier if you just set up a regular HTTP endpoint.  You're already using ASP.Net after all.  This feels like overkill.

Comment: I work mostly with desktop applications and I am not very familiar with web technologies. Can you please show me a "Hello World" link example of your idea?

Comment: Follow any Web Api tutorial, or any ASP.Net webforms tutorial dealing with file uploads.

Comment: I forgot to mention but also other solutions are welcomed.